# Simple python IF statement not working?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

In my code, I am trying to check a specific line of a config file by using linecache to read the line and an if statement to see if it is True, but for some reason it refuses to work.

I simplified the code in order to test it.

```
import linecache

d = linecache.getline('logconfig.dat', 2)

print(d)
if d == True:
    doeslock = True
else:
    doeslock = False

print(doeslock)
```

No matter what I try, `print(d)` will print `True`, and `print(doeslock)` will print `False`. I even tried using letters and strings instead of bools. Still didnt work. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance guys

EDIT:

When I used strings to do the comparison, I replaced the `True` in the file with a y and modified the if statement to see if the `d` variable is 'y'

EDIT 2:

Ok guys I found the problem. Turns out the linecache returned both the line I want and the previous one for whatever reason. I separated the config into two files and now it works fine. No idea what caused this to happen but oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does `print(repr(d))` print?

Comment: You say "I even tried using letters and strings", but you don't show us what you tried. So it remains the most likely cause.

Comment: As @kojiro says, we know that the `('True' == 'True')` comparison will evaluate to the logical `True`.  So we need you to show us the entire context of your program.  There are things that might have subtle changes to the behavior of the comparison or other system features that you may unintentionally invoke.

Answer (score 3):

When you read a line from a file, you get the *whole* line, including the newline character, as a string. You should strip that off and then compare with another string:

```
if d.strip('\n') == "True":
```

Comment: This is a good point, and probably accounts for the "I tried using strings" confusion.

Comment: Even better to use `d.strip()` to cover some other possible whitespace.

Comment: @Lawrence or just `"True" in d`

Comment: That's not it. The file is written through a different script that I wrote. It doesn't include a '\n' in the write function

Comment: @ThsiseFaek if you discover that we have limited information to help you with, please edit the question to include it.

Comment: @ThsiseFaek a normal `open('afile', 'w').write(…)` will add a newline.

Comment: Tell me exactly what else you need. The script that writes the file is just two simple write functions. The first one includes a '\n' but the second one (The one that writes to the second line obviously) does not. I simplified the problematic code down to what I posted (I copy pasted it and removed a couple of lines in the 'else' part of the statement).

Comment: @ThsiseFaek provide code that demonstrates writing to a file without appending a newline. Further please prove that when that when linecache reads that file the result has no newline.

Comment: Well, I dont write to an existing file. It is created on the spot, the two lines are written and then it is closed again. I even tried manually editing the file and it didnt change anything. But I found a workaround so everything is good now. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The string is not the same as the boolean value. Consider:

```
>>> d = 'True'
>>> print(d)
True
>>> if d == True:
...   doeslock = True
... else:
...   doeslock = False
... 
>>> print(doeslock)
False
>>> bool('False')
True
```

What you probably want is:

```
import linecache

d = (linecache.getline('logconfig.dat', 2)).strip()

print(d)
doeslock = (d == 'True')

print(doeslock)
```

Also consider the following:

```
>>> with open('randfile', 'w') as whatever:
...   whatever.write('y')
... 
>>> import linecache
>>> d = linecache.getline('randfile', 1)
>>> print(d)
y

>>> d == 'y'
False
>>> 'y' in d
True
>>> d.strip() == 'y'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`linecache.getline` returns a string, not a boolean. So you have to compare `d` to `"True"`. You also may have to strip the result of getline in case there are spaces or newline.

```
>>> if d=="True":
...   print 'ok'
...
ok
```

Comment: Like I said in the post, I thought of that and tried using strings instead of bools. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try if d.strip() == 'True': 
may be you have an extra space or a \n.

Answer (score 0):

import linecache

d = linecache.getline('logconfig.dat', 2)

print(d)

if d:

```
doeslock = True
```

else:

```
doeslock = False
```

print(doeslock)